# Create a new variable from conditions on multiple variables in R using ifelse condition

Tags: r, arrays, database, dataframe, if-statement

I am  really new to R.
I have a table named `RWA2010LONG` containing 65 variables. I want to create a new variable named `NEWVAR` from the 30:49th variable of the table `RWA2010LONG` and from another variable of the same table named (`BIRTH`) based on the following condition: for each row, if one of the values of the variables 30:49 of the table `RWA2010LONG` is equal to the value of the variable `BIRTH`, `NEWVAR` takes the value `1`. Otherwise, `NEWVAR` takes the value `0`
This is what I tried to do:

```
RWA2010LONG$ NEWVAR <- for (i in colnames(RWA2010LONG[30:49])){ifelse(i==RWA2010LONG$BIRTH, 1,0)}
```

Comment: Could you please provide subset of the data with `dput(RWA2010LONG)` or even a picture

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach. Since you didn't provide data, I am making up some sample data and checking if any values in columns 5 through 10 are the same as `BIRTH`:

```
#Example data
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnbinom(100, mu = 5, size = 0.5), ncol = 10,
             dimnames = list(c(sprintf("obs_%s", 1:10)),
                             c("BIRTH",sprintf("col_%s", 2:10)))))

df$newvar <- apply(df[,5:10] == df$BIRTH, 1, any)*1
```

The `apply` statement checks for the condition `df[,5:10] == df$BIRTH` by row (the `1` indicates apply the condition by row, if for future reference, if you put a `2` it will check the condition by column) and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the condition is met. The `*1` converts those logicals to a numerical value.

Output:

```
#            BIRTH col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7 col_8 col_9 col_10  newvar
# obs_1      0     3     4     0     6    18     0    10     5      7      1
# obs_2      5     1     0     7     5     0     2     2     2      3      1
# obs_3      1     2     4     2     1    13    14     1     2      8      1
# obs_4      1     0     0     0    11     0     0     0    15      0      0
# obs_5      1     9     1     0     4    27     2     1     0      0      1
# obs_6      5     1     0     2     0     7     2     4     0      0      0
# obs_7      1     0     0     6     0     0     1     5     0      0      1
# obs_8     44     0    15     1     1     0     1     1     0      6      0
# obs_9      6     6     0     0     0     4    17     0     6      1      1
# obs_10     0     2     0     0     2    11     2     1     9      2      0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code works properly

Comment: Glad it helped! If there are no better answers, consider accepting it as the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An option with `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
       mutate(newvar = +(if_any(5:10, ~ .x == BIRTH)))
```